# Invalid Installed application named real?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, virus, uninstall, filesystem-corruption

Whenever I enter the program **your uninstaller** in my laptop, the following message of a newly installed application is shown:

[image]

with the following properties:

[image]

I press the **AutoFix** button and there's a message shown that says **this corrupted installation has been fixed**

[image]
[image]
[image]

But if I exit **your uninstaller** and enter it  or refresh the programs list, it is shown at the top as a newly installed program again.
**What is this? Is this a kind of virus?

And what's wrong with the windows that shows this as an installed program?**

Comment: Have you ensured the system is clean of viruses and malware? If yes, what did you use.

Comment: @CharlieRB I just use microsoft security essentials

Comment: That is a start. MSE doesn't catch everything, so I'd suggest doing an addition scan with eSet's online virus scanner. Then download and run Malwarebytes to ensure the system is clean of malware.

Comment: Why Re you using a third-party software to install and uninstall applications which do exactly what add/remove program does

Comment: @Ramhound add/remove programs does not remove the programs completely including their registery keys

Comment: both run the uninstaller, the program in question, doesn't magically know what in the registry belongs ton application.